# How to rowSums by group vector in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame such like:

```
df<-data.frame(A.1=1:5,B.1=2:6,C.1=3:7, 
               D.2=4:8,E.2=5:9,F.2=6:10)
df
  A.1 B.1 C.1 D.2 E.2 F.2
1   1   2   3   4   5   6
2   2   3   4   5   6   7
3   3   4   5   6   7   8
4   4   5   6   7   8   9
5   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

What I wanted is to `rowSums()` by a group vector which is the column names of `df` without Letters (e.g. `c(1,1,1,2,2,2)`) and the output would be:

```
      1  2
[1,]  6 15
[2,]  9 18
[3,] 12 21
[4,] 15 24
[5,] 18 27
```

My real data set has more than 110K `cols` from 18 groups and would find an elegant and easy way to realize it.

Comment: The dim is 33694 x 166438

Comment: compressed one is 500M

Comment: I gave you a thumb of your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: I created a vector instead.

Comment: @李哲源 something like this `data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, sub('^.\\.', '', names(df))), rowSums))
`

Comment: I have done it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
 mutate(ones = rowSums(select(., grep(".1", names(.), value = TRUE))),
        twos = rowSums(select(., grep(".2", names(.), value = TRUE)))) %>% 
 select(ones, twos)

  ones twos
1    6   15
2    9   18
3   12   21
4   15   24
5   18   27
```

Answer (score 3):

`rowsum` can do this:

```
t(rowsum(t(df), c(1,1,1,2,2,2)))

      1  2
[1,]  6 15
[2,]  9 18
[3,] 12 21
[4,] 15 24
[5,] 18 27
```

(For whatever reason, there is no `colsum`.)

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way `data.frame`s are structured internally, row-wise operations are generally much slower than column-wise operations. Given your comment about how large this `data.frame` actually is, I would probably use `data.table` to convert it to long, isolate the group as its own variable, and perform a group-wise sum.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  A.1 = 1:5,
  B.1 = 6:10,
  C.2 = 11:15,
  D.2 = 16:20
)
```

First, convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` using `setDT`.

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
```

Then, add a `row_number` column (`:=` creates a new column; `.N` is a special variable containing the number of rows in the table).

```r
df[, row_number := 1:.N]
```

Convert this to a "long" `data.table`, using `row_number` as the unique ID column.

```r
df_long <- melt(df, id.vars = "row_number")
df_long
#>     row_number variable value
#>  1:          1      A.1     1
#>  2:          2      A.1     2
#>  3:          3      A.1     3
#>  4:          4      A.1     4
#>  5:          5      A.1     5
#>  6:          1      B.1     6
#>  7:          2      B.1     7
#>  8:          3      B.1     8
#>  9:          4      B.1     9
#> 10:          5      B.1    10
#> 11:          1      C.2    11
#> 12:          2      C.2    12
#> 13:          3      C.2    13
#> 14:          4      C.2    14
#> 15:          5      C.2    15
#> 16:          1      D.2    16
#> 17:          2      D.2    17
#> 18:          3      D.2    18
#> 19:          4      D.2    19
#> 20:          5      D.2    20
```

Create a new `group` column that is everything after the "." in the new "variable" column (`^.*?\\.` is everything from the beginning of the string to the first "."; `gsub(pattern, "", variable)` removes `pattern` from `variable`).

```r
df_long[, group := as.integer(gsub("^.*?\\.", "", variable))]
df_long
#>     row_number variable value group
#>  1:          1      A.1     1     1
#>  2:          2      A.1     2     1
#>  3:          3      A.1     3     1
#>  4:          4      A.1     4     1
#>  5:          5      A.1     5     1
#>  6:          1      B.1     6     1
#>  7:          2      B.1     7     1
#>  8:          3      B.1     8     1
#>  9:          4      B.1     9     1
#> 10:          5      B.1    10     1
#> 11:          1      C.2    11     2
#> 12:          2      C.2    12     2
#> 13:          3      C.2    13     2
#> 14:          4      C.2    14     2
#> 15:          5      C.2    15     2
#> 16:          1      D.2    16     2
#> 17:          2      D.2    17     2
#> 18:          3      D.2    18     2
#> 19:          4      D.2    19     2
#> 20:          5      D.2    20     2
```

Finally, do `sum(value)` grouping by `row_number` and `group`.
These sorts of operations are blisteringly fast in `data.table`, significantly faster and more efficient than base R.

```r
df_long[, sum(value), by = list(row_number, group)]
#>     row_number group V1
#>  1:          1     1  7
#>  2:          2     1  9
#>  3:          3     1 11
#>  4:          4     1 13
#>  5:          5     1 15
#>  6:          1     2 27
#>  7:          2     2 29
#>  8:          3     2 31
#>  9:          4     2 33
#> 10:          5     2 35
```

Answer (score 0):

Using library `dplyr` and `reshape2`. You can execute each line by line (without th trailing %>% to understand the transformations. The basic idea is to `melt` it into  tidy(tall) format to manipulate rows, then to `dcast` it back into wide format

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
df %>% 
  # assign a row number for later grouping
  mutate(rn=row_number()) %>%
  # make into a tall data frame, with rn as the row key
  melt(id.vars = "rn") %>% 
  # calculate the row suffix for grouping
  mutate(suffix = str_extract(variable, "\\d+")) %>%
  # put it back into a dataframe, summing value (could use acast if you want an array)
  dcast(rn ~ suffix, value.var="value", fun.aggregate = sum)

#   rn  1  2  
# 1  1  6 15
# 2  2  9 18
# 3  3 12 21
# 4  4 15 24
# 5  5 18 27
```